# Adding an Accordion-Like Setup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I want to be able to add the whole Accordion Aspect to this code in jsFiddle. To where if you expand one, and then click on another it collapses the previous div and displays the most recently clicked.

Any idea of how I could accomplish this through this jsFiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/zrbFE/

Thank you all!

Comment: use jquery ui accordion http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fAmWx/1/

This might help get you started in the right direction. The idea is to simplify and reuse class names and code.

Comment: This one works fully, when I collapse it though the content closes half way and then just dissappears instead of fully opening and fully closing? Any idea?

Comment: Not sure. You can slow down the slide - http://jsfiddle.net/fAmWx/2/ Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does sir! That helped a lot! Thank you! One more question: How do I get the image to return to it's original SRC once I click on another ITEM? http://jsfiddle.net/fAmWx/7/ . The image isn't reverting to it's original state when I click on another EXPAND ITEM.

Answer (score 1):

I made this some time ago, think it will suit your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/aCaEG/2/

Comment: Awesome! But how would I apply this to my jsFiddle Code? Seeing as I am using DIVs opposed to an Unordered List?

Comment: @AaronBrewer Both divs and ul:s are display: block. You shouldnt have any problem applying this to your divs. Seems like jsfiddle is down for me at the moment.

Comment: jsFiddle is back up. Thank you so much by the way! :)

Answer (score 1):

I like this library for that functionality:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion.html

Way lighter than jQuery UI, and works beautifully. Check that page for examples of how to mark it up and call it in your script.

Comment: I can't have a DIV that is displayed on default. Thank you though!

Comment: This library will allow you to collapse everything on default, or show a specific accordion tab, or show all of them.  It's designed to be totally customizable.  If you leave out the "display: block" in the example, everything will display collapsed on default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your jsfiddle:

```
function toggleMe(me) {
    var alreadyOpen = me.is(':visible');
    jQuery('div[class^="content-"]').hide('fast');
    if (!alreadyOpen) {
        me.show('slow');
    }
}
jQuery('.expand-one').click(function() {
    toggleMe(jQuery('.content-one'));
    var img = $(this).find('img'),
        src = img.attr("src"),
        alt = img.data("altsrc");
    img.attr("src", alt).data("altsrc", src);
});
/// SECOND SESSION:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
jQuery('.expand-two').click(function() {
    toggleMe(jQuery('.content-two'));
    var img = $(this).find('img'),
        src = img.attr("src"),
        alt = img.data("altsrc");
    img.attr("src", alt).data("altsrc", src);
});
```

Hope this helps,

Pete

Comment: This seems to do the job, but if I click on the same one it closes it and then re-opens and it also doesn't apply the IMAGE Code if I click on an "EXPAND" Div.

Comment: Okay, modified to collapse if clicked twice. I removed the toggle functions as toggle is built into jquery already, there's no need to redefine it. As far as the IMAGE code, there are no image declarations in the source HTML for your jsfiddle. Add them to test your swapping of alt and src.